# -[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

```
      _data = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSNumber *value1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 5.0f];
    [_data setValue:value1 forKey:@"foothold"];
    NSNumber *value2 = [_data valueForKey:@"foothold"];
    NSLog(@"a foothold  %f ",[value2 floatValue]);//error here
```

It's strange, but I don't see my error...

Comment: Use the `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` methods, not the "value" methods.

Comment: no such methods for mutable array

Comment: Are you trying to use a dictionary perhaps?

Comment: Oops. It's an array, not a dictionary. Do what I said but also change `_data` to a `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. `_data` is mistakenly an `NSMutableArray` instead of an `NSMutableDictionary`.
2. Don't use `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` unless you mean to do KVC.
3. Use modern syntax (it's easier and it avoid issue #2).

Updated code:

```
_data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSNumber *value1 = @5.0;
_data[@"foothold"] = value1;
NSNumber *value2 = _data[@"foothold"];
NSLog(@"a foothold  %f ",[value2 floatValue]);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error, you'll be given the name of the method you're attempting to call (in this case `floatValue`) as well as the type of object you're calling it on (`NSArray` here).

So in this case, despite `value2` being declared as an `NSNumber`, the value returned from `[_data valueForKey:@"foothold"];` is an `NSArray`, which does not respond to the `floatValue` selector.

I'm surprised you weren't given other warnings.  Given the syntax, it looks like you should be using an `NSMutableDictionary` rather than an array.  In which case, try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSNumber *value1 = @5.0f;
_data[@"foothold"] = value1;
NSNumber *value2 = _data[@"foothold"];
NSLog(@"a foothold %f", [value2 floatValue]);
```